# DNS Suffix Search List in wrong order

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, dns, windows-domain

I'm having a bit of trouble with the DNS Suffix Search List. I have changed the order (Network Settings > Right Clicked on Relevant Connection > Properties > Internet Protocol  (TCP/IP) > Properties > Advanced > DNS > Checked "Append these DNS Suffixes (In Order) ), i enter the DNS Suffxes (dnssuffix1, dnssuffix2, dnssuffix3) and click OK. Then when i do a "ipconfig /all" it lists it as dnsuffix2, dnssuffix1, dnssuffix3 when in should be in order.

Comment: did you try disabling and enabling the NIC? sometimes changes won't take effect until this or a reboot is done.

Comment: Yes, but still no luck. could it be something somewhere in the registry forcing this?

Comment: Have you checked your DHCP server scope options? Can set these settings there as well.

Comment: Yes, everything in there is fine - someone else who is getting there settings from the same DHCP server isn't effected by this.

Comment: next place I would check is group policy. under Computer configuration > administrative templates > network > dns client. In the policy that might be attributed to your computer in AD.

Comment: Also checked here mate, nothings been set for local group policy. There's also not a gpo being pulled down from AD as my colleague who's getting his gpo's from the same place would be effected too.